# Double click on .py tkinter file doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, command-line

So.. When I'm trying to run my Tkinter script, that opens and closes immediatly a command prompt window, but the script run perfectly good when I launch it from the native Python IDLE...

I have tried to change .py to .pyw, to launch it from command line..

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from subprocess import call
import webbrowser
import sys
import os

window = Tk()
window.title("xx's App")
window.geometry("600x400+100+100")
window['bg'] = "white"

#We define all the function here
def webSite_yofr():
    webbrowser.open_new("http://x")
def webSite_cf():
    webbrowser.open_new("http://xx")
def webSite_ga():
    webbrowser.open_new("https://xxx") 
def webSite_dream():
    webbrowser.open_new("https://xxxx.fr")
def appLeaving():
    print("Leaving..")
    window.destroy()
def loginScript():
    print("App has started")
    call(["python", "LoginPage"])

topbarMenu = Menu(window)
optionsMenu = Menu(topbarMenu, tearoff=0)
topbarMenu.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=optionsMenu)
optionsMenu.add_command(label="Leave app", command=appLeaving)

#Sous menu site web
siteMenu = Menu(topbarMenu, tearoff=0)
topbarMenu.add_cascade(label="Site web", menu=siteMenu)
siteMenu.add_command(label="x", command=webSite_yofr)
siteMenu.add_command(label="xx", command=webSite_ga)
siteMenu.add_command(label="xxx", command=webSite_cf)
siteMenu.add_command(label="Le domaine de mes réves..", command=webSite_dream)

#Titre application
text1 = Label(window, text="L'application de la xx's xx", background="white")
text1.configure(font=("Comic Sans Ms", 15, "bold"))
text1.pack()

#saut de ligne
textSL = Label(window, text=" ", background="white")
textSL.pack()

#Bouton se connecter
button1 = Button(window, text="Commencer !", command=loginScript)
button1.configure(font=("Comic Sans Ms", 12, "normal"))
button1.pack()


window.config(menu=topbarMenu)
window.mainloop()
```

Please help me

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Just write `python myfile.py` in command line

Comment: Didn't work.. As you can see:  https://ibb.co/Vq1Tjf1

Comment: I think the script `mainpage.py` does not contain the last line `window.mainloop()` actually.  So it works fine in IDLE, but not in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @acw1668 I've effectively forgot to put `window.mainloop()` at the end of my code ahah